# mod.rs and nested modules in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to specify a generic trait `Engine` and provide two different implementations: `Random` and `Dummy`. I want to use following file structure:

```
src-
  |-engine
    |-mod.rs //contains Engine trait code
    |-random.rs // contains first engine implementation
    |-dummy.rs // contains second engine implementation
```

I have something like this in **lib.rs**:

```
pub mod engine {
    // random moves engine
    pub mod random;
    pub mod dummy;
}
```

When I try to add `use engine::Engine` anywhere in my other modules, it can't be found:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `engine::Engine`
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you write curly braces in a `mod` item, that tells the compiler that the module's contents are within these braces, not in an external file. Thus, the compiler doesn't even look at `engine/mod.rs`. When you write a semicolon instead, the compiler will look for an external file.

What you need to do instead is put these lines in `engine/mod.rs`:

```
pub mod random;
pub mod dummy;
```

And in `lib.rs`, write:

```
pub mod engine;
```